# Using asctime_s and could do with someone explaining the argument types c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a timestamp for my program and output it. At the moment I have two errors when compiling:

1. Error   1   error C2664: 'errno_t asctime_s(char *,size_t,const tm *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'tm *' to 'char *'
2. 2   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "asctime_s" matches the argument list
           argument types are: (int, char [256], tm *)

The documentation I am looking at for this is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6htak9c.aspx

I have the following code:

```
char buffer[256];
time_t rawtime;
tm timeinfo;
errno_t result = localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
cout << "Current local time and date: " << asctime_s(256, buffer, &timeinfo) << endl;
```

Which then displays "no instance of overloaded function "asctime_s" matches the argument list, argument types are : (tm *, time_t *)" However using a pointer to timeinfo and rawtime causes further errors with the localtime_s.

Could someone please explain this to me as I do not really understand the documentation.

Kind Regards

**Edit**

Having changed the code to

```
char buffer[256];
time_t rawtime;
tm timeinfo;
errno_t result = localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
cout << "Current local time and date: " << asctime_s(buffer, &timeinfo) << endl;
```

It now runs however I get the following popup error message can anyone advise? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JFby.png

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `asctime_s` should be a character array; you are passing a pointer to a `tm`, which looks like it should be the second argument.  The second error is just saying that it can't find a version of `asctime_s` that matches the types you passed in your call.

Comment: Having changed the code to 
    char buffer[256];
    time_t rawtime;
    tm timeinfo;
    errno_t result = localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
    cout << "Current local time and date: " << asctime_s(buffer, &timeinfo) << endl;


It now runs however I get the following popup error message can you please advise? 
http://i.imgur.com/yuVaWKe.png

Comment: Sure: you never initialized `rawtime` with the time you want to display.

Comment: Will it not display the current date and time though? I've tried it initialized as null and 0. It there anyway to get it to display the current date and time?

Comment: You need a separate call to get the current time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx